# Error when using build on private repository

Tags: git, docker, go, github, docker-compose

I am in a team of 2 persons in a homework in university the we created o private repository on github cloned from a public repository. We are using GO language, docker and docker-compose. All the imports in GO come from the public repository. The person who created the private repository don't get errors when trying to build but I get errors and I can't build it. I clone private repository with ssh forwarding my key with ssh-agent. The public repository is "github.com/ucy-coast/cs499-fa22" and the go module name is "github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/". The private repository is github.com/ucy-coast/username/cs499-fa22. I get the following messages.

```
go: finding module for package github.com/sirupsen/logrus
go: finding module for package gopkg.in/mgo.v2
go: finding module for package google.golang.org/grpc/reflection
go: finding module for package golang.org/x/net/context
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
go: finding module for package google.golang.org/grpc
go: finding module for package google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/profile/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/hailocab/go-geoindex
go: finding module for package github.com/uber/jaeger-client-go/config
go: finding module for package github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-opentracing/go/otgrpc
go: finding module for package github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go
go: finding module for package google.golang.org/grpc/keepalive
go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2
go: downloading github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go v1.2.0
go: downloading google.golang.org/grpc v1.50.1
go: downloading github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-opentracing v0.0.0-20180507213350-8e809c8a8645
go: downloading github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.9.0
go: downloading github.com/hailocab/go-geoindex v0.0.0-20160127134810-64631bfe9711
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.2.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/mgo.v2 v2.0.0-20190816093944-a6b53ec6cb22
go: downloading github.com/uber/jaeger-client-go v2.30.0+incompatible
go: found github.com/sirupsen/logrus in github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.9.0
go: found github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go in github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go v1.2.0
go: found github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-opentracing/go/otgrpc in github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-opentracing v0.0.0-20180507213350-8e809c8a8645
go: found github.com/hailocab/go-geoindex in github.com/hailocab/go-geoindex v0.0.0-20160127134810-64631bfe9711
go: found google.golang.org/grpc in google.golang.org/grpc v1.50.1
go: found google.golang.org/grpc/keepalive in google.golang.org/grpc v1.50.1
go: found google.golang.org/grpc/reflection in google.golang.org/grpc v1.50.1
go: found github.com/golang/protobuf/proto in github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2
go: found golang.org/x/net/context in golang.org/x/net v0.2.0
go: found google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure in google.golang.org/grpc v1.50.1
go: found github.com/uber/jaeger-client-go/config in github.com/uber/jaeger-client-go v2.30.0+incompatible
go: found gopkg.in/mgo.v2 in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 v2.0.0-20190816093944-a6b53ec6cb22
go: downloading github.com/stretchr/testify v1.7.0
go: downloading google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200526211855-cb27e3aa2013
go: downloading github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6
go: downloading google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.2.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/check.v1 v0.0.0-20161208181325-20d25e280405
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.4.0
go: downloading github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/stretchr/objx v0.1.0
go: downloading github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c
go: downloading golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/profile/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/uber/jaeger-lib/metrics
go: finding module for package gopkg.in/yaml.v2
go: finding module for package go.uber.org/atomic
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/pkg/errors
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/uber/jaeger-lib/metrics/metricstest
go: downloading github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1
go: downloading github.com/uber/jaeger-lib v2.4.1+incompatible
go: downloading go.uber.org/atomic v1.10.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: found github.com/pkg/errors in github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1
go: found github.com/uber/jaeger-lib/metrics in github.com/uber/jaeger-lib v2.4.1+incompatible
go: found go.uber.org/atomic in go.uber.org/atomic v1.10.0
go: found github.com/uber/jaeger-lib/metrics/metricstest in github.com/uber/jaeger-lib v2.4.1+incompatible
go: found gopkg.in/yaml.v2 in gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: finding module for package github.com/HdrHistogram/hdrhistogram-go
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/profile/proto
go: downloading github.com/HdrHistogram/hdrhistogram-go v1.1.2
go: found github.com/HdrHistogram/hdrhistogram-go in github.com/HdrHistogram/hdrhistogram-go v1.1.2
go: downloading gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20200227125254-8fa46927fb4f
go: downloading github.com/niemeyer/pretty v0.0.0-20200227124842-a10e7caefd8e
go: downloading github.com/kr/text v0.2.0
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/profile/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo/proto
github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/frontend imports
        github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/profile/proto: cannot find module providing package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/profile/proto: module github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/profile/proto: git ls-remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/25d7ecce62d5217dbfc309e95fa0935ac3442cda3276f618cce8defe7a0cec32: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo imports
        github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo/proto: cannot find module providing package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo/proto: module github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/geo/proto: git ls-remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/25d7ecce62d5217dbfc309e95fa0935ac3442cda3276f618cce8defe7a0cec32: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate imports
        github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate/proto: cannot find module providing package github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate/proto: module github.com/ucy-coast/hotel-app/internal/rate/proto: git ls-remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/25d7ecce62d5217dbfc309e95fa0935ac3442cda3276f618cce8defe7a0cec32: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
ERROR: Service 'profile' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go mod tidy' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: You explain that you setup your ssh keys and stuff, but it is trying to use https instead of ssh for some of the addresses there.... so i don't think that the ssh setup will hold water.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your setup, you can try this.

Add these lines in `~/.gitconfig` file

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```